# Audio from Youtube embedded video keeps playing after web view is closed - Flutter

Tags: webview, flutter

I am creating a webview using flutter_webview_plugin in Flutter with MaterialPageRoute.

```
 Navigator.of(videoContext).push(
      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
             return new WebviewScaffold(
                 url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/fq4N0hgOWzU",
                 appBar: new AppBar(
                         title: new Text("flutter"),
                         backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                         ),
                       );
                  }));
```

After clicking back button on top-left, webview is closed but audio keeps playing.

Example on plug in page does not help. 
 (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-example-tab-)

I will really appreciate if someone can show me the right direction.

[UPDATE]
This looks like a issue on Assus Zenfone 5(android 4.4) model.
Code is working fine on Moto G3.

Comment: you should change or reload the url before you leave the current route, i have the reference with code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447533/flutter-how-to-turn-off-youtube-video-in-webview-after-back-event/55465063#55465063

Answer (score 1):

> Don't forget to dispose webview

```
 flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose()
```

from the [documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-readme-tab-)

Comment: I am not creating the instance of flutterWebviewPlugin i.e. webview is not created using flutterWebviewPlugin.launch() so is there a way to dispose without creating the instance?