# Flutter - How to turn off youtube video in webview after back event?

Tags: dart, flutter

So i just implemented this WebView in  flutter and it's great, but there's a problem when i embedd a youtube video using webview, the video is still playing even i close the Webview page. How do i turn it off?

the plugin that i use is **flutter_webview_plugin**

```
final flutterWebviewPlugin =FlutterWebviewPlugin();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.close();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
  }
```

and this is the widget:

```
IconButton(
   icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
   onPressed: () {
   print('Hello there!'); flutterWebviewPlugin.launch('https://www.youtube.com/embed/m5rm8ac4Gsc');
},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a route and but inside it your webview example: `/youtubeWebview` and use `Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/yourRoute');` to go back instead of `Navigator.pop(context);`

Comment: sorry but still not working, the audio still there even the app is minimize, i even try to use this `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', (Route<dynamic> route) => false)` instead of what u suggest, but still no luck. but thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the answer but i change the package to `webview_flutter` instead of `flutter_webview_plugin`.

To stop the audio from youtube or any other website that has audio we need to change the `url` of the current webview. and maybe it will work with `flutter_webview_plugin` too.

```
/* define webview controller */
WebViewController _controller;

/* before we leave current route, make sure to change the url to something */
Future<bool> _willPopCallback(WebViewController controller) async {
  controller.loadUrl('https://www.google.com/'); /* or you can use controller.reload() to just reload the page */

  return true;
}

return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () => _willPopCallback(_controller), /* call the function here */
  child: Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Just appbar'),
     ),
     body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialUrl: widget.videoUrl,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) { /* i am not sure what this line actually do */
                  _controller = webViewController;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'Please pause the video before you go back',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```